# Почему не удаляются строки в представлении MySQL?

Tags: mysql, view, mysql-workbench

Вот представление:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему не получается удалить строки?

delete from p_p where наименование="МосквА";

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В представлении используется join поэтому MySQL не знает из какой таблицы удалять. Такие представления невозможно изменять. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-updatability.html

Answer (score 0):

Db view существует как алиас(синоним) для какого либо запроса на выборку. Так как в запросе могут использоваться несколько таблиц разработчики исключили возможно изменять данные напрямую, в следствии чего оно не двусмысленно называется view.

Comment: Вообще то если в view только одна таблица и соблюден еще ряд условий, то менять ее можно.

Comment: а если в представлении с одной таблицей код: delete dostup_tovar where id_товара=1; не удаляет строку в представлении?

Comment: Удалять можно данные из таблицы, а не из view. View содержить только данные для чтения